# Repainting after maximizing

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, paint

I have a WinForms form containing many controls. On resizing the form, I need to place and resize the components and redrawing pictures in `PictureBox`es.

I had problems with flickering, so now I call `SuspendLayout` at the beginning of the `SizeChanged` event (and `ResumeLayout` at the end).

But it was not enough, so I use a boolean variable indicating, if the form should be repainted. I set it to true at `SizeChanged` event and false after the Paint event. This solved the problem, because for some mysterious reason the Paint event was raised incredibly often.

The form still did not repaint correctly sometimes. I solved that by calling `SizeChanged` method in `ResizeEnd` event (and I don't know why it worked).

Now almost everything works, but after maximizing/unmaximizing the form, the pictures in the `PictureBox`es are not repainted. Everything is sized and placed right, except for the pictures, which have the same size (but the `PictureBox`es are resized). I have no idea why or what else I can do (except for disabling maximizing).

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Call the PictureBox.Invalidate() method at the end of SizeChanged (before you ResuleLayout).

Comment: The Form does have DoubleBuffered=true, I hope..

Comment: @TaW Why the form?  That wouldn't affect PictureBoxes, which have DoubleBuffered = true by default.

Comment: Because he talks about the Paint event of the Form. At least if I read it right..

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you, but it doesn't work. It works for changing the form size, but not for maximizing.

Comment: Show us the code.  You have stuff happening in a bunch of places we can't see.

Comment: It does work. If it doesn't for you, then you're doing something wrong. From reading your question, it sounds like you're doing *lots* of things wrong. You need to [edit] your post and include your code. You're asking us to speculate wildly on what appears to be a totally inappropriate way of doing things.

Comment: @TaW Yes, the form is double-buffered. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, the problem is repainting the images in PictureBoxes.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot so we can better understand the situation? - Also: Why do need to draw Image onto(?) the PictureBoxes in the first place? The Image should take care of itself!